# Stop Office Interop Copy/Paste from ignoring region settings

Tags: c#, office-interop

Am working with Office Interop (can't use OOXML) and want to copy a table from an Excel file into an RTF file.

So first i copy the table in Excel

```
excelSheet = excelBook.Worksheets[1];
excelBook.CheckCompatibility = false;
excelRange = excelSheet.Range["B12:F21"];
excelRange.Copy();
```

Then in Word (with the RTF open) i paste it

```
wordApplication.Selection.Find.Execute(placeholder);
WordRange range = wordApplication.Selection.Range;
if (range.Text.Contains(placeholder))
    range.Paste();
```

Placeholder contains the text i use as code to know where to paste it in

Now in that excel table i have cells formated as currency, and so they contain data in the form `3,56 €` but after the paste, what i have in Word (RTF file) is `3.56 $`- notice the change from `,` to `.` and from `€` to `$`

However if i do all this manually (open the Excel file in Excel, select all cells from the table, press `ctrl+C`, open the RTF in Word, position the cursor and press `ctrl+V` - i get the correct value (euros).

Any ideas how i do this work programatacly as it does manually?

Comment: can't you specify culture in an overload on `Paste`?

Comment: @JensKloster nope - Paste receives no params and has no overloads

Comment: Do you have to use Office Automation to put the data into the Word document? Could you alternatively create or modify an .rtf file in your C# code? RTF is not all that complicated for creating a simple document, or modifying a boiler-plate document. Then launch Word to display the result.

Comment: @JensKloster Potentially yes - and i do that with other replacements by treating the rtf as text file - but how would i go about pasting content from Excel in that manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found a little workaround - thanks to @JensKloster for the idea

After pasting the table (as in the question) i load up the rtf as text into a variable and apply the following:

```
cnt = Regex.Replace(cnt, @"(?<main>\d+)\.(?<decimals>\d{2,3})", "${main},${decimals}").Replace("$", "€");
```

This seams to do the job (at least for now i found no issues with the current rtf templates in use - although issues could show up easilly in the future

Pending someone smarter giving me a better option, this will become the answer